# page with 15 text box

Tags: boxes, text

I don't know if this is correct:
I need a page (vertical A3) that contain 5 vertical rule each line is composed by 3 column. I need to insert text on this box.
How can I obtain that?

Thank you

Renato

ps
this is an example of first page[image]

Comment: Can you add a sketch?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a vertical rule that is composed by (of?) 3 columns.  I don't understand where the box comes from that you're wanting to insert text into.  I second the request for a sketch.  Do you mean that you need a 3 column by 5 row grid, with text in each of those boxes?  Have you looked into creating a table?

Comment: Thanks for adding the image. I think the `poster` library from the `tcolorbox` package might be useful.

Comment: Or `tikzposter`, but I've been told `tcolorbox`'s package is better.

Comment: ok for tcolobox package, but I don't need colored box. The blue character is just becausethis is the title of text and it is an hyperlink. Can you send me an example that I can convert in my need?

Comment: I can obtain simple result with the simple tabular environment. How can I made a large table that spread in all the page(one page)

Comment: Try using the multicol package  https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Multiple_columns. alterative `longtable`  with suitable width of cells would do it tabularray? Personally I would go for multicol.

Comment: multicol wouldn't keep the rows lined up.  I'd say `{tabular}{ *{3}{p{.3\textwidth}} }`.

Comment: @Teepeemm: can you explain me well this statement?

Comment: @Teepeemm You could use one `\begin{multicols}{3}…\end{multicols}` per row. Nevertheless, it looks more like a longtable (but don't forget `\tabcolsep`).

Answer (score 1):

I think the following will get you started.  `tabularx` creates a table that is `\linewidth` wide (the width of the page).  The `*{3}{X}` creates 3 type `X` columns, which `tabularx` makes equally sized to become the desired width.  Within a tabular cell, you can then enter the title and abstract (using `\newline`, since `\\`  starts a new tabular row).  And then move to the next cell with `&` and the next row with `\\` .

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a3paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand\shortBox{This is a short box}
\newcommand\longBox{This is a longer box that will take some more space.  I'll add some more words to make sure that happens.  I think this is enough. Well, lets add a bit more. This is a longer box that will take some more space.  I'll add some more words to make sure that happens.  I think this is enough. Well, lets add a bit more.}
\begin{document}
\centering
{\Huge This is my title}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2} % increase the spacing between the rows
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ *{3}{X} }
Title 1\newline\shortBox &
Title 2\newline\longBox &
Title 3\newline\shortBox \\
Title 5\newline\longBox &
Title 4\newline\shortBox &
Title 6\newline\shortBox \\
Title 7\newline\shortBox &
Title 8\newline\longBox &
Title 9\newline\shortBox \\
Title 10\newline\shortBox &
Title 11\newline\longBox &
Title 12\newline\longBox \\
Title 13\newline\shortBox &
Title 14\newline\longBox &
Title 15\newline\shortBox
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image: code output]